# How to make SRWare Iron Portable open links from other apps in already opened browser window?

Tags: browser, srware-iron

Links clicked in other applications, like MS Office or instant messengers open up in new browser window. It wouldn't be much of a problem, but that windows doesn't use any extensions or styles I have installed, which makes it almost unusable.

Of course, Iron is set as a default browser.

I need to know how to make Windows/Iron open links in the window that is already opened, or - if there isn't any - in a new window, but with all my extensions and profile data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open RegEdit and navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` and replace `%PathToIronPortableFolder%\Iron\Iron.exe` with `%PathToIronPortableFolder%\IronPortable.exe`

(you probably want to do same thing for https entry that is just below `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT_\http\...`)

Comment: That's don't work, plugins are not working anymore with this regedit modification. You must put your profile in the windows user apps folder setting !

Comment: Yep, this solution no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Editing `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command` instead of `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` seems to work for newer versions (51 at the moment I'm writing this).

Also, put the following value `"%PathToIronPortableFolder%\IronPortable.exe" "%1"`. By default there is a `--` that makes it open a second tab, probably because new IronPortable executable add some options to underlying Iron.exe process.